# How to show top 10 largest items from git history

Tags: command-line, git

I found this command to get the top 10 largest files from my git history (in this closed issue https://github.com/18F/C2/issues/439)

```
git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-7b03cc896f31b2441f3a791ef760bd28495697e6.idx \
| sort -k 3 -n \
| tail -10
```

It now shows something like this:

```
32f0dac6ee67325ca12b9c03279ee2dbc7790567 blob   12732444 11425432 1091676437
c63c2851049c51eabbcd54cb46cad367d4e0d593 blob   14368670 12189261 246241495
```

What do these numbers represent? What of them is the file size? Also I would be very grateful if anyone could break down and explain the top command. I don't understand it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To reduce the space used by files, git packs objects stored in the repository into a `.pack` file. This pack file contains the actual git objects and the `.idx` contains the index used to quickly locate objects within the pack file.

```
$ git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-7b03cc896f31b2441f3a791ef760bd28495697e6.idx
```

The above command reads the given `.idx` file and verifies it with the corresponding pack file. Using `-v` you get a verbose output.

The third column in the output is the size of the objects. Using `sort -k 3 -n` we are sorting the output numerically using the 3th column (based on size) and with `tail -10` we are cutting out the last 10 which are the largest in size.

To get the name of files from their hash:

```
$ git ls-tree -r HEAD | grep HASH
```

---

To get a list of all names:

```
$ git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-1daab5282d01ab18db98e21a985eb2d288f7faa0.idx | sort -k 3 -n | tail | cut -f1 -d' ' | while read i; do git ls-tree -r HEAD  | grep "$i"; done

100644 blob 6209b3840fa470a534e670cff93bce698ba60819    .bashrc
100644 blob 1131e7127cb2cf6c1f854f728a1794262cdf85f6    .vimrc
100644 blob a249a5ae9b33553f4484da42a019ed14e5f44e21    .vim/colors/clrs.vim
100644 blob f329f223953827e59954f67ad4d76568b6dd894e    .config/openbox/rc.xml
```

---

Read more:

> $ git verify-pack --help

[Unpacking Git packfiles](https://codewords.recurse.com/issues/three/unpacking-git-packfiles)

[Git Internals - Packfiles](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles)

[Git - finding a filename from a SHA1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460331/git-finding-a-filename-from-a-sha1)

Comment: Is the size given as byte or bit?

Comment: It's in Bytes...

Comment: Hm, when I do `git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-1daab5282d01ab18db98e21a985eb2d288f7faa0.idx | sort -k 3 -n | tail | cut -f1 -d' ' | while read i; do git ls-tree -r HEAD  | grep "$i"; done` I get no output.

Comment: What if you run `git gc` first? Also your `idx` file might have a different name!  Use `find .git/ -name *.idx` to find it!

Answer (score 5):

Here is another neat solution to this problem using git's `ls-tree` sub-command:

```
$ git ls-tree  -rl HEAD | sort -k4 -n | tail | awk '{print $4, $5}' |
numfmt --to=iec-i

4.0Ki  .bashrc
4.0Ki  .config/conky/conky.conf
4.5Ki  .config/rofi/config.rasi
5.4Ki  .vim/notes
7.2Ki  .config/tint2/tint2rc
7.5Ki  .bash_functions
7.5Ki  .vimrc
19Ki   .vim/colors/clrs.vim
38Ki   .config/openbox/rc.xml
63Ki   .config/ipfilter.dat
```

- `-r` to list the files recursively.
- `-l` to show object size of blob (file) entries.
- `sort -k4 -n` sort numerically based on 4th column.
- `tail` cut out the last 10 item.
- Using `awk` to only get the 4th and 5th column out out the output.